# How can I see data loaded from a script dynamically?

Tags: php, html, arrays

Okay the following script is functional but not very good. 
I am posting data in array and in bulk to a `exec` command. 
Everything works and after some time I get an array back with my results. This is the problem it takes a very long time.
I would prefer to see the results as they are fetched so I would like to see the array come together line by line in my PHP script instead of one big block of data.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <textarea name="mp" cols="60" rows="10">0|1|2</textarea>
        <br />

    Delim:
        <input type="text" name="delim" value="|" size="1" />&nbsp;

        data1:
        <input type="text" name="mail" value="0" size="1" />&nbsp;

        data2:
        <input type="text" name="prx" value="1" size="1" />&nbsp;

    <input type="submit" value=" send " name="btn-submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");

    if (isset($_POST['mp'], $_POST['delim'], $_POST['btn-submit'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['prx'])) {
        $mps = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['mp']);

        // Create an array to store results
        $result_data = array();

        // Iterate over requests
        foreach ($mps as $mp) {
            $mp = explode($_POST['delim'], $mp);

            // Store the account details in variables
            $email = $mp[$_POST["mail"]];
            $proxy = $mp[$_POST["prx"]];

            // Prepare a reusable string
            $result_string = "/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js \"" . $email.  "\" \"" . $proxy . "\" 2>&1";

            // Add result to the array
            $result_data[] = $result_string;
        }

        // Store of results complete. We now display them.
        if (count($result_data)) {
            foreach ($result_data as $result_data_entry) {
                echo exec($result_data_entry);
            }

            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
?>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I still need help with this i am looking for something more simple then symphny maybe and ajax script that can handle the html araay and post the data back from php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Symfony Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) component which supports incremental output.

Example:

```
foreach ($mps as $mp) {
        // ...

        $result_string = new Process("/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js \"" . $email.  "\" \"" . $proxy . "\" 2>&1");
        $result_data[] = $result_string;
    }

    // Store of results complete. We now display them.
    if (count($result_data)) {
        while (count($result_data_entry) > 0) {
            foreach ($result_data_entry as $i => $process) {
                if (!$process->isStarted()) {
                    $process->start();
                    continue;
                 }

                 echo $process->getIncrementalOutput();

                if (!$process->isRunning()) {
                    unset($result_data_entry[$i]);
                }
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is very interesting just having a read now :) thanks can you show examples that i could use in conjunction with my script

Comment: thanks again i just need to learn this it seems so complicated but hey more learning curve for me

Comment: I added an example of how you might use it (You might need to tweak the example code a bit so it works for you)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in PHP. PHP is executed all server-side, not client side. That means that the results are all found *before* sending it to the user. You could, however, use Javascript to do this. I'm not sure how you would do it, but there's probably a way to dynamically see the results of a query.

Comment: Thanks i will look into this i didnt think php done this this is why i ask for ways i can achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
flush();
```

after

```
echo exec($result_data_entry);
```

?